# Incrementar data Ionic 3, Angular, Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ionic3

Gostaria de saber como faço para incrementar a data de vencimento de uma compra. Exemplo: a pessoa realizou uma compra, e colocou a data de vencimento para o dia 30 de março, então a data da segunda parcela seria 29 de abril. Segue a função e o código HTML.

```js
<ion-card *ngFor="let p of parcelasCobranca; let i = index">
  Parcela
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Valor: {{ valorParcela }}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Data de vencimento *</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="date"  formControlName="due_date" name="due_date" id="due_date"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item *ngIf="due_date.hasError('required') && due_date.touched">
    <p>Digite a data *</p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

```html
parcelas() {
  this.parcelasCobranca = [];
  this.valorParcela = this.amount / this.quantidadeParcelas;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.quantidadeParcelas; i++) {
     this.parcelasCobranca.push({
       due_date:this.due_date.value,
       value: this.valorParcela,
     });
   }

   console.log(this.parcelasCobranca)
 }
```

**Atualização 1** - segue o outro código que fiz, a data de vencimento está retrocedendo alguns dias.

```js
parcelas() {

  this.parcelasCobranca = [];
  this.valorParcela = this.amount / this.quantidadeParcelas;
  let someDate = new Date(this.due_date.value);

  for (let i = 0; i < this.quantidadeParcelas; i++) {

    someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + 30);


    let dd = someDate.getDate();
    let mm = someDate.getMonth();
    let y = someDate.getFullYear();

    let someFormattedDate = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + y;

    this.parcelasCobranca.push({

      due_date: someFormattedDate,
      value: this.valorParcela,

    });
  }

  console.log(this.parcelasCobranca)
}
```

```html
<ion-grid [hidden]="!value">
  <ion-card *ngFor="let p of parcelasCobranca; let i = index">
    Parcela
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Valor: {{ valorParcela }}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Data de vencimento *</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="date"  formControlName="due_date" name="due_date" id="due_date"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item *ngIf="due_date.hasError('required') && due_date.touched">
      <p>Digite a data *</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>
</ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomendo o uso da biblioteca [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), em seu método `parcelas()` crie uma variável:

```
let data = moment(this.due_date.value);
```

No `for` deixe assim:

```
parcelasCobranca.push({
  value: this.valorParcela,
  due_date: moment(data).format('L'),
});
// A cada loop adiciona 30 dias em data
data = moment(data).add(30, 'days');
```

#### Exemplo funcionando:

```js
let amount = 2000;
let parcelasCobranca;

let quantidadeParcelas = document.querySelector('#quantidadeParcelas');
let due_date = document.querySelector('#due_date');

function parcelas() {
  parcelasCobranca = [];
  let parcelas = parseInt(quantidadeParcelas.value);
  let valorParcela = amount / parcelas;
  let data = moment(due_date.value);
  for (let i = 0; i < parcelas; i++) {
    parcelasCobranca.push({
      value: valorParcela,
      due_date: moment(data).format('L')
    });
    // A cada loop adiciona 30 dias em data
    data = moment(data).add(30, 'days');
  }
  console.log(parcelasCobranca);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/locale/pt-br.js"></script>
Parcelas: <input type="number" id="quantidadeParcelas" value="1" min="1" />
<input type="date" id="due_date" />
<button id="gerarParcelas" onclick="parcelas()">Parcelas</button>
```

Comment: Cara, vlw pela ajuda, era isso mesmo que eu queria. Porém queria tirar uma dúvida, tinha refeito o código aqui,porém quando coloco uma data ela está retrocedendo alguns dias. Exemplo, eu coloco a data do primeiro vencimento para o dia 30 de março, porém quando mando imprimir no console a data de vencimento aparece 28 de março. Vou colocar esse código no post.

Comment: Você fez igual está aqui ?

Comment: Tá um pouco diferente

Comment: Use a biblioteca [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) irá facilitar muito no trabalho com datas, basta ver o tanto de linhas de código que escreveu e olhar para o da resposta.